# adding mongoDB to web app that is working with postgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postgresql, backend

I have a simple web applicatoin with nodeJS backend and postgreSQL database.
I need to add a mongoDB database that will also save the state off the application as backup.

Is it possible to add it without changing the app structure in a simple way?
my code:

postgres.js file:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost'
  database: 'tasks',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
});

const getTasks = (request, response) => {
    // get tasks query
};

const getTaskById = (request, response) => {
    // get task by id query
};

const createTask = (request, response) => {
    // create task query
};

const updateTask = (request, response) => {
    // update task query
};

const deleteTask = (request, response) => {
    // delete task query
}

module.exports = {
    getTasks,
    getTaskById,
    createTask,
    updateTask,
    deleteTask
};
```

index.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

const db = require('./db/postgres')

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
});

app.get('/tasks', db.getTasks);
app.get('/tasks/:id', db.getTaskById);
app.post('/tasks', db.createTask);
app.put('/tasks/:id', db.updateTask);
app.delete('/tasks/:id', db.deleteTask);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How complicated is the state of the application and how do you intend on keeping it updated? Perhaps using MongoDB as store for state snapshots is over-complicating things. Storing JSON in Redis is possibly a simpler route.

You should perhaps also ask yourself why you need to save the sate of the application if you already have the postgres database. What state does your backend produce that is auxiliary to the data in postgres?

Comment: It's a very simple app that is saving new tasks and done tasks for the user. Using the Mongo database is a requirement of the project so I have to add it and I'm looking for the simplest way to do it :)

Comment: Adding application state for "a very simple app" into MongoDB seems like a surefire way to over-complicate things! But it's out of your hands then. I also fail to see why postgres wouldn't store the data of if the tasks are done or not. Why would you use MongoDB if you already have postgres is beyond me.

Comment: I undestand that, but as I said it's a requierment of the project I'm working on: "The server will be a REST API based server which will save the state off the application on PostgreSQL and MongoDB (as backup)". So I'm just looking for a way to make it work.

Comment: Backing up postgres in a MongoDB database makes absolutely no sense. I would question this if I where you. There are excellent tools for how to do efficient backups of postgres databases, and none of them involve MongoDB.